# Why is there an apostrophe in the name Ilya M. Sobol'?

Tags: apostrophe, names

Is this specific to the Lithuanian language? How come I've never seen an apostrophe at the end of a name like this (other than possessives)?

See [Ilya M. Sobol'](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ilya_M._Sobol%27) on Wikipedia.

Comment: Voting to close this because Googling "Russian transliteration" and then looking at his (Russian) name on that Wikipedia page would give you the answer.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it a simple matter of Russian transliteration.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it is not about standard English.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

### It's a diacritic marker

The key is in the original Russian name: Илья Меерович Соболь. The last letter there (ь) is a [soft sign](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Soft_sign), which is sometimes represented by an apostrophe in transliteration systems, such the one used by the [Library of Congress](https://www.loc.gov/catdir/cpso/romanization/russian.pdf). [Ukrainian](https://www.speakua.com/soft-sign-and-apostrophe-in-the-ukrainian-language/) works similarly, except they often just use the apostrophe instead of a letter.

This same apostrophe is found in [Kievan Rus'](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kievan_Rus%27) (Ки́евская Русь) and this etymology for [бюллетень (Kazakh)](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/%D0%B1%D1%8E%D0%BB%D0%BB%D0%B5%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%8C):

> Borrowed from Russian бюллете́нь (bjulleténʹ), from French bulletin, from Italian bullettino, from Latin bulla.

It can also be found inside words, such as with [Vasil'ev](https://www.google.com/books/edition/Encyclopaedia_of_Contemporary_Russian/tZHCAQAAQBAJ?hl=en&gbpv=1&dq=apostrophe%20soft%20russian%20transliteration&pg=PR65&printsec=frontcover).

To most native speakers of English, it means nothing and may be confused with a regular apostrophe. Judging from the other people (and entities) by the [name of "Соболь" on Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?search=%D0%A1%D0%BE%D0%B1%D0%BE%D0%BB%D1%8C&title=Special%3ASearch&ns0=1), it's usually omitted entirely.

Comment: 'To native speakers of English, it means nothing' and thus is off-topic on ELU.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth Sorry, that wording was an oversight. What I mean to say is that this mark is highly specialized in nature, almost like jargon.

Comment: I'd say it's still way too far from standard English usage to belong on ELU. Linguistics, probably.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth I disagree. It's something that is being used in English writing, on English Wikipedia. This is exactly the type of complicated, niche English question that separates ELU from ELL.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth How are transliterated names not part of English?

Comment: One more use for the apostrophe, and this one is actually audible.

Comment: Most of the hits I see in a search for << Ilya M. Sobol' >> transliterate leaving out the diacritic marker. That would seem to be standard English.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth Looking at Google, it seems that some of the hits have the apostrophe stripped from the title while others didn't have it to start with. However, if you check [his works](https://books.google.com/books?id=P5jWKfR91OkC&printsec=frontcover#v=onepage&q&f=false), his name does have it. I don't see why you're bringing up standard English — this is a site for people who aren't satisfied with only knowing about the most basic English facts.

Comment: So do we accept different scripts that appear in English texts as being on-topic? Can you find a work addressing the English language licensing this diacritic?

Comment: @EdwinAshworth There is no other script; I'm not reading Russian Cyrillic (which as I point out doesn't even use an apostrophe here). And since this is English, there is no "licensing", only usage. You can find the same usage on sites in English that aren't Wikipedia and for names that aren't this name. Also it would be good if you could open a meta question on this instead of us continuing here in the comments.

Comment: Can you find a work addressing the English language licensing this diacritic? ELU values reasonably supported rather than anecdotal answers. Britannica, the World History Encyclopedia, the History Channel ... Anglicise, dropping the diacritic.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth Is my edit what you're looking for?

Comment: What has struck me as odd about some contemporary transliterations is their use of consonants in a manner that is unknown in the target language, following a different set of rules;  this strange (i.e. unfamiliar) use of the apostrophe would fall into that general category. Why is it **qi** or **ki** now and not **chi**, for example?

Comment: At the home page: 'Specialized fonts may be required for proper display.' Ė and 'over-brackets' are also included in Library-of-Congress–required transliterations from Russian. This is far better on Literature.